# Trouble with the command "-exec ls -l {} "

Tags: ls, exec

I was working on a lab and was having trouble with the function of part of a command we are supposed to learn. Here it is:

`find . -name "*.txt" -exec ls -l {} \;`

I have determined that the `find . -name "*.txt"` is finding all files in the current directory with the extension .txt, however I am not sure what `-exec ls -1 {} \;` is doing within the command. Any help or basic explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: Also, read the [man page for `find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), especially the section for the `-exec` action.

Comment: Please note the difference between "ls -l" and "ls -1".

Answer (score 1):

If we split this by parts:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

- `find .` = Find all files/directories starting from the current directory
- `-name "*.txt"` = Filter only files/directories with names ending in `*.txt`
- `-exec` = Execute the following command for each file

  - `ls -l {}` = Run `ls -l` (`{}` gets substituted with the name of the file)
  - `\;` = end of command